# Objective-c How to define a MACRO with weak self

Tags: objective-c, macros, automatic-ref-counting, pragma, reference-counting

I have a debug macro which prints the pointer of the object calling the log as well as other information pertinent to the code that it is called from.

```
#define Dlog [Log .... formatArgs:ARGS(f,##__VA_ARGS__)]

#define ARGS @{@"self" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",self],@"file" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[@__FILE__ lastPathComponent]],@"line" : @(__LINE__),@"function" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",__FUNCTION__],@"fmt" :[NSString stringWithFormat:(f), ##__VA_ARGS__]}
```

Problem is that self is strongly retained when `DLog` is called from within a dispatch_block_t

for instance

```
// someObject is kind of SomeClass
[someObject retainBlockAndThenCallItInTheLateFuture:^{
   Dlog("Great"); // self is strongly retained inside the block and causes a memory cycle
}];
```

What I would like to have is a way to implicitly "weakify" self inside this macro so that it would appear to be like:

```
__weak __type__of(self) weakSelf = self;
someSortOfBlock = ^ {
/// using only "weak self"
Dlog(@"Some message with weak self")
}
```

How can I assure that "self" is weak inside the macro?

Comment: You can't. So your best recourse is to define two variations of the macro, one using `self` and the other using `weakSelf` assuming that is what you typically call it (I myself use `this` for `weakSelf`, less typing).

Comment: I think there is an arc pragma to allow this behavior

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I would add self to the Dlog call so that it is clear to the caller that self is being used and they will do the weak self dance.